# What's the concept of and differences between Framebuffer and Renderbuffer in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, rendering, framebuffer

I'm confused about concept of Framebuffer and Renderbuffer. I know that they're required to render, but I want to understand them before use.

I know some bitmap buffer is required to store the temporary drawing result. The back buffer. And the other buffer is required to be seen on screen when those drawings are in progress. The front buffer.
And flip them, and draw again. I know this concept, but it's hard to connect those objects to this concept.

What's the concept of and differences of them?

Comment: Renderbuffer is channel-like components (color,stencil,depth and etcs) of Framebuffer. See: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/OpenGLESontheiPhone/OpenGLESontheiPhone.html

Comment: The link is iPhone specific, but framebuffers are well explained.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

[This page](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_fbo.html) has some details which I think explain the difference quite nicely. Firstly:

> The final rendering destination of the OpenGL pipeline is called [the] *framebuffer*.

Whereas:

> **Renderbuffer Object**
>   In addition, renderbuffer object is newly introduced for offscreen rendering. It allows to render a scene directly to a renderbuffer object, instead of rendering to a texture object. Renderbuffer is simply a data storage object containing a single image of a renderable internal format. It is used to store OpenGL logical buffers that do not have corresponding texture format, such as stencil or depth buffer.

Answer (score 241):

The **Framebuffer** object is not actually a buffer, but an aggregator object that contains one or more attachments, which by their turn, are the actual buffers. You can understand the **Framebuffer** as C structure where every member is a pointer to a buffer. Without any attachment, a **Framebuffer** object has very low footprint.

Now each buffer attached to a **Framebuffer** can be a **Renderbuffer** or a **texture**.

The **Renderbuffer** is an actual buffer (an array of bytes, or integers, or pixels). The **Renderbuffer** stores pixel values in native format, so it's optimized for offscreen rendering. In other words, drawing to a **Renderbuffer** can be much faster than drawing to a texture. The drawback is that pixels uses a native, implementation-dependent format, so that reading from a **Renderbuffer** is much harder than reading from a texture. Nevertheless, once a **Renderbuffer** has been painted, one can copy its content directly to screen (or to other **Renderbuffer**, I guess), very quickly using pixel transfer operations. This means that a **Renderbuffer** can be used to efficiently implement the double buffer pattern that you mentioned.

**Renderbuffers** are a relatively new concept. Before them, a **Framebuffer** was used to render to a **texture**, which can be slower because a texture uses a standard format. It is still possible to render to a texture, and that's quite useful when one needs to perform multiple passes over each pixel to build a scene, or to draw a scene on a surface of another scene!

The OpenGL wiki has [this page](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Renderbuffer_Object) that shows more details and links.

Comment: Thanks! Explaining it as kind of like structs and pointers makes much more sense to me.

Comment: This is still a bit confusing for me. If renderbuffer allows only quick copy to another render buffer, then there's almost no use for it! If I have to do a post-processing stage (like SSAO) isn't more easy rendering it to default framebuffer using previously rendered to Textures than rendering it to a RenderBuffer and then copying back to screen?

Comment: Render buffers are not designed for custom post-processing. They can be used to store depth and stencil information for a draw procedure. This is possible because only GPL implementation itself needs to read renderbuffer data, and tends to be faster than textures, because uses a native format.

If you need post processing, use textures.