# Difference between Frame buffer object, Render buffer object and texture?

Tags: opengl-es-2.0

what is the Difference between Frame buffer object, Render buffer object and texture? In what context they will be used?

Comment: See a question.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213030/whats-the-concept-of-and-differences-between-framebuffer-and-renderbuffer-in

Comment: @shree "It allows to render a scene directly to a renderbuffer object, instead of rendering to a texture object." Why do we need to render to render buffer or Texture we need to render to frame buffer object right?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A framebuffer object is more or less just a managing construct. It manages a complete framebuffer at a whole with all its sub-buffers, like the color buffers, the depth buffer and the stencil buffer.

The textures or renderbuffers comprise the actual storage for the individual sub-buffers. This way you can have multiple color buffers, a depth buffer and a stencil buffer, all stored in different textures/renderbuffers. But they all together make up a single logical framebuffer into which you render.

So a final fragment (you may call it pixel, but actually isn't one yet) written to the framebuffer has one or more color values, a depth value and a stencil value and they all end up in different sub-buffers of the framebuffer.

Comment: thanks for the replay. GOt an Idea of frame buffers so they are final rendering buffers. But how about these render buffer ? i know textures but why and when must we use render buffers?

Comment: @Megharaj Renderbuffers were needed at the time framebuffer objects were introduced since textures couldn't be used as depth or stencil attachments, I think, let aside multisample framebuffers. But with the advent of multisample textures renderbuffers are not really needed anymore. They basically just provide the storage for a buffer of memory to be rendered into, but cannot be used for much else.

Comment: @ChristianRau Could one then safely use textures instead of renderbuffers in *every* offscreen rendering conditions (in ES 2.X)?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I'm not so certain about OpenGL ES. I'm pretty sure ES doesn't support multisample textures. So if you need a multisampled FBO, you will need a renderbuffer. Likewise if ES doesn't support depth or stencil textures (not sure about that). So no, definitely not *every* condition.

Answer (score 36):

### Framebuffer

A framebuffer is not actually a buffer. It's an abstraction for an object that defines parameters for a draw operation. It's a small object that holds one or more *attachments*, which are themselves the actual buffers. Understand the framebuffer as a C struct with many fields. Each field (each *attachment* in OpenGL terms) can be a pointer to a render buffer, texture, depth buffer, etc.

### Texture

An array of standard pixels. This is an actual buffer and can be attached to a framebuffer as the destination of pixels being drawn. Each pixel in a texture typically contains color components and an alpha value (a pixel in the texture can be translated from and into an RGBA quad with 4 floats).

After drawing to the framebuffer that contains a texture attached, it's possible to read pixels from the texture to use in another draw operation. This allows, for instance, multi-pass drawing or drawing a scene inside another scene.

Textures can be attached to a shader program and used as samplers.

### Renderbuffer

An array of native pixels. The renderbuffer is just like a texture, but stores pixels using an internal format. It's optimized for [pixel transfer](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Transfer) operations. It can be attached to a framebuffer as the destination of pixels being drawn, then quickly copied to the viewport or another framebuffer. This allows implementing of [double buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering#Double_buffering_in_computer_graphics) algorithms, where the next scene is drawn while the previous scene is exhibited.

A renderbuffer can also be used to store depth and stencil information that is used just for a single draw procedure. This is possible because only the implementation itself needs to read renderbuffer data, and tends to be faster than textures, because uses a native format.

Because this uses a native format, a renderbuffer **cannot** be attached to a shader program and used as a sampler.

Comment: The most clearest explain about these buffers I've ever heard, and point out the different use cases of each objects. Great!